# Why doesn't alias foo='echo "This is a quote: \'"' work?

Tags: zsh, quoting

In order to remind myself when I try to use `shopt` in Zsh instead of `setopt`, I created the following alias, testing it first at a shell prompt:

```
$ alias shopt='echo "You\'re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."'
```

Despite the outer single quotes matching and the inner double quotes matching, and the apostrophe being escaped, I was prompted to finish closing the quotes with:

```
dquote > _
```

What's going on?

It appeared that the escaping was being ignored, or that it needed to be double-escaped because of multiple levels of interpretation...  So, just to test this theory, I tried double-escaping it (and triple-escaping it, and so on) all the way up until:

```
alias shopt='echo "You\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash." '
```

and ***never*** saw any different behavior.  This makes no sense to me.  What kind of weird voodoo is preventing the shell from behaving as I expect?

The practical solution is to not use quotes for `echo`, since it doesn't really need any, and to use double quotes for `alias`, and to escape the apostrophe so it is ignored when the text is `echo`ed.  Then all of the *practical* problems go away.

Can you help me?  I need resolution to this perplexing problem.

Comment: @muru: I would *never in a million years* see that other question and think it would provide an answer to my question.  The first paragraph in and I have no idea what he's talking about.  Wrapping a command _for_ another command??? What does that even mean?  There's too much noise from the specifics of his situation to use that as a general question for all quoting problems involving both single and double quotes.

Comment: See also [How to use a special character as a normal one?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Comment: @styrofoamfly I'm not asking for a mnemonic... how can it be considered the same question?  Having the same subject matter (quotes) does _not_ make it the same question.

Comment: those answers answer your question if you cared enough to read them

Comment: There is nothing about those answers that give anyone with this same question a reason to expect to find an answer there.  Whether the answer to this question is buried somewhere in the answers to those questions is irrelevant.  What matters is _are those the same questions?_ and they most certainly are not.

Comment: @iconoclast, if it's a single underlying question *dressed up in two entirely different ways*, that's exactly why we **have** the close-as-duplicate mechanism: To guide people to a single source for canonical answers, from multiple paths, thus providing multiple sets of keywords that lead to the same destination. This is why questions closed as duplicates can still be upvoted, aren't automatically deleted, etc -- duplicates are valuable and help the site, when they use sufficiently different terms to describe the same problem as to bring a different audience to that same destination.

Comment: @iconoclast, ...*not* closing a question as a duplicate just because it's asked in different ways leads to a place where there's no community consensus on a single set of answer, but rather competition between the two. That's unfortunate -- it spreads out the answers, and the folks who review/comment/upvote those answers, between those distinct yet equivalent-at-their-core questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: you're the first person I've ever heard articulate even a slightly strong case for your approach to closing questions, but I still disagree.  I think you're confusing two _questions_ as the same just because the same bit of information can answer both.  Those are not the same question in different "clothes".  They are quite literally different questions.  I think you're looking at this backwards.  These sites are _organized by questions, not by answers_.  You perceive duplication because you're trying to organize by answer (or information in the answer).

Comment: If the SE sites were intended to be organized _based on the information in the answer_ then they would need a different data model  Each question would have to be **classified** by the information in the answer, and each question/answer pair would be an instance of the class.  But there are no classes in SE sites.  The data model doesn't support the kind of organization that you want.  I'm not saying it would be _bad_ to do it the way you propose _if the site actually supported it with it's UI and data model_ and that intent were explicitly stated, but it *is* bad in the current site.

Comment: The page with the "class" for the questions would need to have the "naked" question (to use your metaphor) without being dressed up at all.  Then the multiple questions "dressed up in different clothes" could be linked to from the page for the class of questions that they belong to.  The class would have the most stripped down version of the question, and the most stripped-down version of the answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

*This is `zsh`, man, not `fish`*.

In `zsh`, like in every Bourne-like shell (and also `csh`), [single quotes are strong quotes, there is no escaping within them](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting) (except by using the `rcquotes` options as [hinted by @JdeBP](/a/437969) where `zsh` emulates `rc` quotes¹). You cannot have a single quote inside a single-quoted string, you need to first close the single quoted string and enter the literal single quote using another quoting mechanism (like `\` or `"`):

```
alias shopt='echo "You'\''re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."'
```

Or:

```
alias shopt='echo "You'"'"'re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."'
```

Though you could also do:

```
alias shopt="echo \"You're looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash.\""
```

(`"..."` are *weaker* quotes inside which several characters, including `\` (here used to escape the embedded `"`) are still special).

Or:

```
alias shopt=$'echo "You\'re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."'
```

(`$'...'` is yet another kind of quotes from ksh93, where the `'` can be escaped with `\'`).

(and BTW, you can also use the standard `set -o` in place of `setopt` in `zsh`. `bash`, for historical reasons, has two sets of options, one that you set with `set -o` one with `shopt`; `zsh` like most other shells has only one set of options).

---

¹ In `rc`, the shell of Plan9, with a version for unix-likes also available, [single quotes are the only quoting mechanism](/a/296147) (backslash and double quotes are ordinary characters there), the only way to enter a literal single-quote there is with `''` inside single quotes, so with `zsh -o rcquotes`, you could do:

```
alias shopt='echo "You''re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."'
```

Comment: Do you have any links to resources that describe how the ksh93 syntax works? Looks handy if that's the *only* thing it does.

Comment: @jpmc26, that's supported by most shells (and [being added to the POSIX standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249)) so you'll probably find it described in your shell's manual. For `zsh`, see [`info zsh Quoting`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting).

Answer (score 14):

```
shopt='echo "You\'
```

This is not voodoo.  This is normal POSIX shell quoting in action.  *There is no escaping mechanism within single-quoted strings*.  They always terminate at the next single quote.  There is a Z shell extension that makes two successive single-quoted strings get a single quote placed between them, which you could employ. Or you could just terminate the single-quoted string, use an escaped (or indeed non-single-quote quoted) single quote, and then start a second single-quoted string.

Or you could not use contractions in your messages.  ☺

## Further reading

- ["Single quotes"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02).  *Shell command language*.  Base Specifications.  IEEE 1003.1:2017.  The Open Group
- ["Quoting"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting).  *Shell Grammar*.  The Z Shell manual.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that "extension"? `'foo''bar'` -> `foo'bar` is how you get literal single quotes in `rc` (where single quotes are the _only_ quoting operator).

Comment: Ah! `set -o rcquotes` in `zsh`.

Comment: Nitpick: I wouldn't use the word "terminate" because the next single quote doesn't terminate the *argument*, though that is what many people mistakenly believe.  The crucial point to understand is that **in the shell, quotes are never delimiters.**  Only whitespace (usually space characters) are delimiters.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers do a good job of explaining why you're seeing this behavior.  But if I may make a suggestion for how to actually solve this problem:

**Don't use aliases for anything even remotely complicated.**

Sure, you *can* tie your brain up in knots trying to figure out how to nest N layers of quotes, but it's rarely worth it for an alias.  When an alias is complicated enough that its quoting becomes nontrivial, just switch to a shell function:

```
shopt(){
    echo "You're looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."
}
```

This removes an entire layer of quotes, allows you to add more code to the shell function later, and is generally much easier to read.  It also allows much finer control over how and where arguments are inserted, instead of the alias approach of "just replace the beginning of the line and let the remaining words fall where they may."  For example, with your (corrected) alias, if you type this:

```
shopt -s some_opt
```

...then you will get this output:

```
You're looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash. -s some_opt
```

That's probably not what you wanted.  The shell function will consume whatever arguments you pass to it, and silently discard them.

Comment: Yes, very good practical advice.  It doesn't actually answer the question, but I'm upvoting it anyway because it's still a useful addition to the conversation.

Answer (score 5):

For days when you don't feel like fighting the quotes, use another character like Unicode U+2019 instead of `'` for apostrophes.

Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and type `u2019` and this character will appear `’` (er... depending on your locale?).

```
% alias shopt='echo You’re looking for setopt. This is a Z shell, woman, not Bash.'
% shopt -s dotglob
You’re looking for setopt. This is a Z shell, woman, not Bash. -s dotglob
```

Such usage of `’` (U+2019) is correct because this character is officially intended to be used as an apostrophe. [*The Unicode Standard, Version 10.0*](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf) explicitly recommends such usage. The standard acknowledges that `'` (U+0027) is commonly used as an apostrophe due to its presence in ASCII and on keyboards, and appears to permit that. But it then states that `’` (U+2019) is *preferred* for apostrophes used as punctuation (and gives a contraction as an example). The only apostrophes for which `’` (U+2019) is not preferred are those used as diacritic marks rather than punctuation marks; those are best written `ʼ` (U+02BC). **From *Apostrophes* (p. 276) in section 6.2 of [the standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf)**:

> #### Apostrophes
>
> U+0027  <sub><sup>**APOSTROPHE**</sup></sub> is the
>   most commonly used character for apostrophe. For historical reasons,
>   U+0027 is a particularly overloaded character. In ASCII, it is used to
>   represent a punctuation mark (such as right single quotation mark,
>   left single quotation mark, apostrophe punctuation, vertical line, or
>   prime) or a modifier letter (such as apostrophe modifier or acute
>   accent). Punctuation marks generally break words; modifier letters
>   generally are considered part of a word.
>
> When text is set, U+2019 
>   <sub><sup>**RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK**</sup></sub> is preferred as
>   apostrophe, but only U+0027 is present on most keyboards. Software
>   commonly offers a facility for automatically converting the U+0027
>    <sub><sup>**APOSTROPHE**</sup></sub> to a
>   contextually selected curly quotation glyph. In these systems, a
>   U+0027 in the data stream is always represented as a straight vertical
>   line and can never represent a curly apostrophe or a right quotation
>   mark.
>
> ***Letter Apostrophe.*** U+02BC  <sub><sup>**MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE**</sup></sub> is preferred
>   where the apostrophe is to represent a modifier letter (for example,
>   in transliterations to indicate a glottal stop). In the latter case,
>   it is also referred to as a *letter apostrophe*.
>
> ***Punctuation Apostrophe.*** U+2019  <sub><sup>**RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK**</sup></sub> is preferred where the character is to represent a punctuation mark, as for
>   contractions: “*We’ve been here before.*” In this latter case, U+2019
>   is also referred to as a *punctuation apostrophe*.
>
> An implementation cannot assume that users’ text always adheres to the
>   distinction between these characters. The text may come from different
>   sources, including mapping from other character sets that do not make
>   this distinction between the letter apostrophe and the punctuation
>   apostrophe/right single quotation mark. In that case, *all* of them
>   will generally be represented by U+2019.
>
> The semantics of U+2019 are therefore context dependent. For example,
>   if surrounded by letters or digits on both sides, it behaves as an
>   in-text punctuation character and does not separate words or lines.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: It is my understanding that ' is also the straight quote (for when you don't know which way it goes).

Comment: Thanks @EliahKagan. I stand corrected. I'll remove my comments.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. Although your previous comments were the impetus for my edit, I think the blockquoted text I added is also generally beneficial (even in the absence of those comments) and worth the length increase. Of course, as the editor who added it, I *would* think that, wouldn't I! *Zanna*: So, although I suggest keeping the full quote, I will not object if you end up deciding to shorten or remove/replace it.

Answer (score 4):

A now-deleted comment tipped me off and got me half-way to the answer.

It's impossible to escape a single quote ***inside a single-quoted string***.

This limitation is not present in double quoted strings, as I'm certainly escaping a single quotation mark inside a double-quoted string in my final solution:

```
alias shopt="echo You\'re looking for setopt. This is Z shell, man, not Bash."
```